# mouseenter mouseleave do not correctly fire on sibling elements

Tags: jquery

I have 3 elements, that are all siblings, yet they are positioned over each other.  I wanted to use mouseenter/mouseleave on these, however, they do not work as expected.  (only the topmost element is firing the mouseenter/mouseleave).  Is there a native jQuery method to deal with siblings elements?  I would like to stay away from checking every element bound on every single mousemove event.

```
----------- OUTER ELEMENT --------------
|                                      |
|  -------  -------                    |
|  |  A  |  |  B  |                    |
|  -------  -------                    |
|                                      |
----------- OUTER ELEMENT --------------
```

defined as html:

```
<div class="outerelement"></div><!-- position absolute, etc -->
<div class="a"></div><!-- position absolute, etc -->
<div class="b"></div><!-- position absolute, etc -->
```

javascript:

```
$('div').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    switch (e.type) {
       case 'mouseenter':
         $(this).addClass('hover');
         break;
       case 'mouseleave':
         $(this).removeClass('hover');
         break;
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ranRf/)

What ends up happening is mouseenter/leave fires when over A/B correctly, but it should fire for the outer element, however it is not ....

Comment: Works just fine for me in Chrome ?

Comment: both the outer and the A should have hover states when over A.  That works for you?

Comment: Nope, but that's not the expected behaviour at all? Why would both have the hover state.

Comment: Because I want the mouseenter event on the outer element.  It's not firing.

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ranRf/4/?

Comment: @j08691 That is really hacky -- there might be unlimited div's here, and I don't want to have to test other elements.  I want an event to fire whenever the mouse is over the element (hence the word "mouseenter").

Comment: Hacky? Hardly given your example. If you have a different scenario or have needs other than what you posted in your question I suggest you list them. Bottom line, is that the effect you're after or not?

Comment: so you're suggesting that if I add 10 more divs "inside" that element I should test the id of each one?

Comment: I'm looking for a true "mouseenter" event, not a fake "mouseenter"

Comment: I don't think you get it, placing the elements with CSS has nothing to do with the events or the order in the DOM, so just placing them on top of each other doesn't magically make the mouse events work the way you want them do, they work exactly the way they should do, you're just expecting something completely different, and that would require hackish solutions.  Why don't you just place them inside each other in the DOM like normal people, solves the issue right away without any javascript -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ranRf/5/**

Comment: this is for a web app, not an html page.  I do not want to inject html into the target dom, therefore, i'm creating proxy elements to determine locations of the target dom.  This is not hacky for an application at all.  I don't think you're understanding what I'm trying to achieve at all -- it should not be difficult to get a mouseenter that always fires when the mouse is within that element.

Comment: Also, the elements are never in a "known" location, therefore I cannot not put elements inside each other.

Comment: lol thanks for the downvote.  I didn't want this to be a "YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG" sort of thread.  I don't understand why asking for a mouseenter event that truly works like a mouseenter event is such a big deal.

Comment: Well, you are doing it wrong, as there is no such event, application or not. The order in the DOM is what counts, not what you see on your screen, it's that simple.

Comment: The order of the dom in this case should NOT matter for a mouseenter event because they are all siblings!  Why would a mouseenter event not fire for the all the elements in question?  There is no reason.

Comment: Exactly, they are all siblings, so when the mouse enters an element that is positioned on top of another element, the mouse leaves the underlying element and is no longer within that element, that's just how it works, has always worked, and probably always will work, as that is the most logical behaviour, anything else would not make any sense.

Comment: "mouseenter", in my realm of logic, denotes an event that is fired when the mouse enters an element.  Not, "enters an element but only if it is also the child of the parent element".

Comment: Exactly, and mouseleave fires when leaving an element, and when moving the cursor to a new element, that just so happens to be positioned over another element, fires the mouseleave event on the underlying element, and the mouseenter event on the top most element, just like you would expect, and just like you would need it to in 99.99% of all cases. The problem, again, is that you are expecting something else than what it really does, and you haven't really understood how the box model works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested with win-chrome only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    div.overlay div {
        position:       absolute;
        border:         1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        height:         100px;
        z-index:        10;
    }

    div.overlay div.hover {
        background-color:   rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    }

</style>
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function(e) {

        var body    = $(this); //.find('body');
        var proxy   = $(this).find('div.overlay');

        var numChildren = 50;
        while (--numChildren) {
            proxy.append(
                $('<div/>').css({
                    'top':  Math.random() * 800,
                    'width':    Math.random() * 800,
                    'height':   Math.random() * 800,
                    'left': Math.random() * 800
                })
            );
        }

        body.on('mousemove', function(e) {

            var children    = proxy.children();
        var x           = e.pageX - window.scrollX;
        var y           = e.pageY - window.scrollY;
            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i) {
                var element = $(children[i]);
                var rect    = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
                if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                    if (!element.hasClass('hover')) {
                        element.addClass('hover');
                        element.triggerHandler('truemouseenter');
                    }
                } else {
                    if (element.hasClass('hover')) {
                        element.removeClass('hover');
                        element.triggerHandler('truemouseleave');
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        ClientRect.prototype.contains = function(x, y) {
            return (x >= this.left && x <= this.right && y >= this.top && y<= this.bottom);
        }

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="overlay"></div>

</body>
</html>
```